# SQL Pivot report - Not Grouping As Desired

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I have a query that returns a 'pivot' result SET. the issue I have is that the parameters I need to match to each timestamp are from slightly different timestamps ---as shown in the image below.

I need to combine each of the 5 parameters ---gty, tmp, rate, mf, prs--- into 1 line under an arbitrary "maxtime" where they ignore the nulls

any ideas??

```
SELECT [time], Tagname, GTY, TMP, FLOW as Rate, MF, PRS
FROM y
PIVOT
(
       max(lastvalue)
       FOR [tag2] IN (GTY, TMP, FLOW, MF, PRS)
) AS P
```

[image: SQL Piv]

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. *SQL* and *pivot table* are both information available from the tags you've used, which means there is zero relevant content in your title. It should be descriptive enough to have significance to future readers who find it in a search result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group it so you get to keep the time portion.
If you need to list all the unique values comma separated instead of max then I have a CLR aggregate function you could use if you are using SQL Server.

```
SELECT max([time]) AS 'time',
       Tagname,
       max(GTY) AS 'GTY',
       max(TMP) AS 'TMP',
       max(FLOW) AS 'Rate',
       max(MF) AS 'MF',
       max(PRS) AS 'PRS'
FROM y
GROUP BY Tagname
```

Or wrap your pivot in a group by

```
SELECT max([time]) AS 'time',
           Tagname,
           max(GTY) AS 'GTY',
           max(TMP) AS 'TMP',
           max(FLOW) AS 'Rate',
           max(MF) AS 'MF',
           max(PRS) AS 'PRS'
    FROM (SELECT [time], Tagname, GTY, TMP, FLOW as Rate, MF, PRS
          FROM y
          PIVOT
          (
          max(lastvalue)
          FOR [tag2] IN (GTY, TMP, FLOW, MF, PRS)
          ) AS P) y
    GROUP BY Tagname
```

Or better yet, use CTE

```
WITH PIV AS 
(SELECT [time], Tagname, GTY, TMP, FLOW as Rate, MF, PRS
FROM y
PIVOT
(
       max(lastvalue)
       FOR [tag2] IN (GTY, TMP, FLOW, MF, PRS)
) AS P)
SELECT max([time]) AS 'time',
           Tagname,
           max(GTY) AS 'GTY',
           max(TMP) AS 'TMP',
           max(FLOW) AS 'Rate',
           max(MF) AS 'MF',
           max(PRS) AS 'PRS'
    FROM PIV
    GROUP BY Tagname
```